# Conditional sentences - usage of "shall" in main clause

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, conditional-constructions

I read [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-sentences/) that in first type of conditional sentences, simple future is used in the main clause. However, it was not clear if only `will` should be used or `shall` can also be used. For example below sentence, is that grammatically correct?

> if I leave now, I shall reach on time

Comment: *Shall reach* doesn't work. You can use *shall arrive*, *shall get there*, or even *shall be*. (And *shall* works just as well as *will*. Which also has the same problem with the use of *reach*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you for your reply. Here my main concern is whether I can use "shall" in first conditional type of sentences or not?

Comment: I don't know much of anything about the so-called *first to fourth conditionals*. Those are guidelines that are never presented to native English speakers. They seem to have been made up for ESL grammar courses. (And they are often too rigid.) I do know that you can replace *will* with *shall* (at least when it comes to future intention or prediction) without a problem. It might sound a little archaic, but it's acceptable.

Comment: @JasonBassford Ah, I see, you are a native English speaker. I am a non-native English speaker and want to learn the grammar rules from international English exams perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use `shall` with the main clause of the first conditional. For example, the below sentence is grammatically correct.

> if we don’t hurry, we shall miss the train